# How to set the exit status code in a Symfony2 command?

Tags: symfony, command-line

What's the proper way for setting the exit status code in a Symfony2 command?

In plain php you can do this with `exit(123)`. But I guess Symfony2 has an OOP way. Is that right? I couldn't find anything on the docs though.

I need this mostly because I want to be able to do something like this in Linux: `app/console my:command || { echo "Something went wrong, I'm gonna call handle_disaster now"; handle_disaster; }`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In the base `Command` class:

```
    if ($this->code) {
        $statusCode = call_user_func($this->code, $input, $output);
    } else {
        $statusCode = $this->execute($input, $output);
    }

    return is_numeric($statusCode) ? (int) $statusCode : 0;
```

So simply return the exit code from your `execute()` function. Your console command will exit with this code as long as it is a numeric value.